# Método POST Web API retorna 'NULL'?

Tags: json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Estou desenvolvendo uma *Web Api com ASP com VB.NET* para receber parâmetros `JSON` e criei um método `post` com o seguinte código.

```
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String) As String
    return value
End Function
```

E esse código tem me retornado sempre `null`, alguém tem ideia do que pode ser?

***Observação:*** estou utilizando o ***APP PostMan*** para realizar a requisição `POST` e esse método recebera uma string `JSON`.

Comment: Como é que você está enviando esse `json`?

Comment: Como ele está retornando o próprio `value` então este, está sendo enviado como `null`. Replico a pergunta do @VirgilioNovic. Como?